# Does Chazakah work to consider someone a Jew?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism

Following [my answer to "natural conversion"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98564/15579), I wondered if there are sources that specifically contradict or support my claim that, similarly to other questionable situation resolved Halachicly by Chazakah, once status as a Jew can be accepted by Chazakah as well.

For example, clothes or watches that one wears are presumably his, if one works in a field for three consecutive years it's presumably his, if one and his girlfriend comes to a new community and cohabit with her he becomes presumably married, if a woman comes from far away and holds a child she continues to fosters for years he becomes presumably her son etc.

Comment: do you have a source for “if one and his girlfriend...he becomes presumably married”?

Comment: You mean חזקה הבאה מכוח הרוב?

Comment: @DanielRoss This is an old discussion about all the Olim from all over the world that come here to Isreal.

Comment: "if one works in a field for three consecutive years it's presumably his". IR: According to the doctrine of “adverse possession”, if property was abandoned, and someone else "squatted" on it for a number of years, the squatter could gain control over the land. Halacha does NOT recognize this doctrine. - According to halacha, even if someone works a field for three consecutive years, he would only be able to establish ownership in Beis Din, if he backed up his presence with a legal claim, טענה, explaining in what legal manner he acquired the field.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer.

### Chezkat Israel

**Tosfot Pesachim 3b.**
From this Tosfot it seems that when a man comes and says he is Jew, if we haven't a chazaka that his parents are not Jews, he is considered as Jew.

> ואנא אכילנא משופרי שופרי. מכאן אין ראיה שנאמין לכל הבא לפנינו ואומר ישראל אני דשאני הכא דרוב ישראל היו ואזלינן בתר רובא אך יש להביא ראיה מפרק החולץ (דף מה. ושם) דאמר ליה זיל גלי או נסיב בת מינך וכן מההוא דאתא לקמיה דרבי יהודה ואמר נתגיירתי ביני לבין עצמי אמר ליה נאמן אתה לפסול את עצמך ואי אתה נאמן לפסול את בניך והיינו משום *דמצי למימר ישראל אני* והא דאמר בהחולץ (דף מו:) מי שבא ואמר גר אני יכול נקבלנו תלמוד לומר אתך במוחזק לך התם מיירי במוחזק לן באבהתיה שהם נכרים דאי לאו הכי נאמן במיגו דאי בעי אמר ישראל אני:‏

**Tosfot Yebamot 45a**
This Tosfot says in the second teruts that we rule as chachamim in kiddushin 62b that all families are in chezkat kashrut.

> זיל איטמר. וישיאוך מיוחסת וא''ת והא בעי ראיה כדאמר בפ''ב בכתובות (דף כד: ושם) דמעלין מתרומה ליוחסין ויש לומר דהתם להשיא בתו לכהן העובד על גבי המזבח כמו שמוכיח שם רבינו תם א''נ התם כר''מ אבל חכמים אומרי' כל משפחות בחזקת כשרות הם עומדות בפרק עשרה יוחסין (קדושין דף עב:):

**Tosfot Yevamot 47a.**
This Tosfot says that the majority of people they're coming to us as Jew are Jewish people.

> במוחזק לך.אומר רבינו תם דדוקא בדידעינן דהוה עובד כוכבים מעיקרא דאי לא הוה ידעינן מהימן מגו דאי בעי אמר ישראל אני דמהימן כדמשמע בריש מסכת פסחים (דף ג: ושם) גבי ההוא עובד כוכבים דהוה סליק ואכיל פסחים בירושלים ואין לומר שאני התם דהוו סמכי ארובא דהוו ישראל דהא בכל מקום נמי איכא רובא *דרוב הבאין לפנינו בתורת יהדות ישראל הם* ועוד ראיה משמעתין דאמר ליה ר''י אי אתה נאמן לפסול את בניך ואיהו גופיה כשר אלא דשוי נפשיה חתיכה דאיסורא אבל אם בא על בת כהן לא פסלה כדפי' לעיל ומההיא דלעיל (דף מה.) דא''ל זיל גלי אין ראיה דשמא לא היו בודקים אלא אם הוא ישראל אם לאו אבל במשפחתו לא היו בודקין:‏

**Tosfot Kiddushin 62b.**

From this Tosfot it seems that if people see that he is shomer mitsvot (for this point I'm not sure 200% that it's equivalent of kabalat ol mitsvot in presence of 3 dayanim ediotot, but this is probable) and see him when he goes to mikve for tevilat Ezra (if the mikve is kosher for tevilat nidda), We need to rule him as a Jew.

> גר צריך שלשה משפט כתיב ביה כדין. נראה דוקא בקבלת מצות הוא דבעינן ג' אבל בטבילה בחד סגיא אם כבר קיבל עליו המצות וראיה מההיא דיבמות (דף מה:)דקאמר התם ההוא דהוו קרי ליה בר ארמאי פירוש משום דמל ולא טבל אמר ריב"ל מי לא טבל לקריו כלומר וכי לא ראה קרי מימיו דצריך לטבול א"כ משמע מדנפיק בטבילת קריו משמע דלא בעינן שלשה ומיהו קשה מהא דאמר (שם דף מז:) דמושיבין אותה במים עד צוארה ושני תלמידי חכמים יושבים מבחוץ ומודיעין לה מקצת מצות קלות ומקצת חמורות ופריך והא בעינן שלשה ומשני תני שלשה אלמא משמע דלטבילה נמי בעינן שלשה ויש לומר דודאי למצוה בעינן שלשה אבל לא לעכב אי נמי י"ל דהא דבעי שלשה היינו טעמא משום קבלת מצות וא"ת משום קבלת מצות נמי אמאי בעינן שלשה והרי הודאות והלואות דכתיב בהן משפט ואפ"ה אמרינן בסנהדרין (דף ג.) דדן אפילו יחידי ויש לומר דיש לנו להשוותן לגזילות וחבלות דלעולם בעי שלשה דכל היכא דאיכא לאקושי לקולא ולחומרא לחומרא מקשינן וא"ת א"כ ליבעי מומחין כמו גזילות וחבלות ויש לומר דשליחותייהו עבדינן כדאמרינן בגיטין (דף פח:) עוד אמר הר"ר נתנאל דבגר כתיב לדורותיכם דמשמע בכל ענין אע"ג שאינן מומחין דעל כרחך השתא ליכא מומחין שהרי אין סמוכין ולדורותיכם משמע לדורות עולם:‏

See SA YD 268 3, A machloket lechatechilla between Tosfot and RIF. See Taz SK 10 and Shach sk11

Comment: +1 Very good quotes. But if you only quote Tosfos, between the lines I read, there's no Halachic discussion on this topic at all. isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand you @Al Berko

Comment: @AlBerko He clearly says "Partial answer." Don't draw conclusions from what is not posted here.