# Does Reform Judaism recognize children of Jewish father as Jews?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, family-members, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, reform-judaism

Does Reform Judaism recognize children of Jewish father as Jews (under conditions that father is Jewish both from mothers and fathers side). If so, that person does not have to go through conversion in order to marry Jewish girl?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52891/759

Comment: why are my comments regarding reform and conservative questions being deleted wholesale? are those not legitimate questions?

Comment: @Tesvov take it to [meta] (where you'll find it's nearly all been discussed already)

Answer (score 2):

In 1983 [the CCAR ruled](https://www.ccarnet.org/responsa-topics/on-patrilineal-descent/) that a person with only a Jewish father could be considered Jewish and be entitled to all the rights thereof **provided that such a person was raised with an exclusive Jewish upbringing**. Otherwise, such a person is not considered Jewish and would have to undergo a valid conversion to Judaism.

Traditional Jewish Law defines a Jew as someone with a Jewish birth mother or as someone who underwent a valid conversion to Judaism through a proper religious court.

Please refer to [this Q&A](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52891/11486) elsewhere on this site.