# What is the process involved in a Beth Din recognition of Jewish status?

Tags: halacha, beit-din-court, baal-teshuva

I was curious if someone could give me a breakdown regarding what the process would be for a person to receive recognition of their status through the **Beth Din**.

I'm not speaking to conversion but of Jews who are Jewish but fell away from the faith from one generation or another. (Grandparents were Jewish but their parents didn't practice, sort of thing)

I have heard of people entering back into the Jewish community by going to the Beth Din to have their Jewish status recognized under an Halachalic legal setting. I was just curious what that process was like.

Comment: Dupe of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52891/9682?

Comment: A person who is Jewish does not need a beth din to do anything to restore his or her Jewish status, regardless of what the parents did. As far as halacha is concerned, that person is Jewish.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, they ask a lot of questions about your family history and will ask for any documentation you might have, including copies of parents'/grandparents' Ketubot (wedding documents) and potentially pictures of tombstones. They may ask you to provide references.

When it's all said and done, they might issue a letter, if that would be needed for instance when moving to Israel.

That's about it; nothing really ceremonial.