# Obligation of a Beis Din to judge and decide on Issurim?

Tags: halacha-theory, beit-din-court, family-members

THe question about [the baby switch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104579/ramifications-of-a-baby-switch) made me think of this question:

In the realm of Issurim (Arayos, Mamzerim, conversion, Kohen, etc) when new evidence arises, is a Beis Din and what Beis Din obligated to judge and decide on it?

For example in the aforementioned case, a DNA report comes from a lab 20 year after the birth showing with a 99% probability that the babies were switched. The two persons enjoy their current Chazokos (maybe already married with kids). What's next - what B"D is obligated/authorized to see the case?

Can a Beis Din deny seeing new evidence? And is it different for different Issurim topics?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12736/759 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18202/759 and probably Too Broad anyway

Comment: We first would need to establish the halachic significance of D.N.A. Tests. See sources cited here: די.אן.איי. בהלכה http://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%93%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9F%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94 המשמעות הראייתית של בדיקות D.N.A. http://www.daat.ac.il/mishpat-ivri/maamarim/hamashmaut-2.htm

Comment: @IsraelReader OK, then, what happens if two Kosher witnesses come and testify - is a Beis Din obligated to judge or it can wave them.

Comment: @AlBerko See Makkos 2a מעידין אנו באיש פלוני שהוא בן גרושה או בן חלוצה etc. It seems that part of BD's responsibility in upholding the the Torah observance of the nation, includes verifying people's lineage, especially if a complaint against a person is lodged by two witnesses.