# Does the lineage cross from mother to son

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

My Great Great Grand Mother was Jewish.  She had three children.  Two deceased not long after birth; one survived.  The surviving child was a male.  Would he be Jewish because of his mother?  Would his children and their children all the way to me be Jewish?

Comment: Mayim, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887)! If you need analysis of your specific situation, I recommend [contacting a rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146), armed with an understanding of the background information provided in [the Q&A linked above](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52891/am-i-jewish).

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and for the answers.

Comment: Note that even if it turns out that your lineage doesn't make you automatically Jewish, it *is* possible for gentiles to convert.